Allow a port from one docker container available to another docker container?
I have one docker container running for selenium/standalone-chrome.
docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome

I have created one more application which uses selenium to run a particular script. When I run this on my local machine it works fine.
But when I make an image out of it with this dockerfile.
FROM node:21.7-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

I run my app like this.
docker run --name my-app-container-1 -p 3000:3000 my-app

I get the following error:
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

I can see that 127.0.0.1:4444 is not accessible inside the container that I just used. How can I allow it, so that it can use this remote server?
I have tried
docker run --network host --name my-app-container-1 -p 3000:3000 my-app


You need to run both containers on the same Docker network.  Each container is its own localhost, and you need to use the other container's name as the hostname.  Also see for example How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname".
